# ARRAYFORMULA and FILRER by a range

Tags: google-sheets, filter, array-formulas

This formula by I2:I not work
in google sheets

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(ifs(B2:B<>"",VLOOKUP(B2:B,FILTER(A!A1:F55,A!D1:D55=I2:I),2,false)),""))
```

Answer (score 0):

In ARRAYFORMULA formulas like QUERY and FILTER not working with non static query (query to some cell without using cells in current talbe).

You must make all queries in ARRAYFORMULA as static.

May you share link to your example?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BfUeAzj8ylESUw9Zbi-urN4PzeX2VlI55b-yE3UwXFg/edit#gid=1175971775

Comment: @sajad no permissions, please open for everyone

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BfUeAzj8ylESUw9Zbi-urN4PzeX2VlI55b-yE3UwXFg/edit?usp=drivesdk